# Find a delimiter of csv or text files in c#

Tags: c#, csv

I want to find a delimiter being used to separate the columns in csv or text files.

I am using TextFieldParser class to read those files.

Below is my code,

```
String path = @"c:\abc.csv";
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
if (File.Exists(path))
{
    using (Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.TextFieldParser parser = new Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.TextFieldParser(path))
    {
        parser.TextFieldType = FieldType.Delimited;
        if (path.Contains(".txt"))
        {       
            parser.SetDelimiters("|");
        }
        else
        {
            parser.SetDelimiters(",");
        }
        parser.HasFieldsEnclosedInQuotes = true;
        bool firstLine = true;
        while (!parser.EndOfData)
        {
            string[] fields = parser.ReadFields();
            if (firstLine)
            {
                  foreach (var val in fields)
                  {
                      dt.Columns.Add(val);
                  }
                  firstLine = false;
                  continue;
             }
             dt.Rows.Add(fields);
          }
     }
 lblCount.Text = "Count of total rows in the file: " + dt.Rows.Count.ToString();
 dgvTextFieldParser1.DataSource = dt;
```

Instead of passing the delimiters manually based on the file type, I want to read the delimiter from the file and then pass it.

How can I do that?

Comment: How do you know what character is the delimiter other then the file extension?

Comment: Could you count the instances of each individual character and assume that the most frequent one is a delimiter?

Comment: It is just an example that I am using to read couple of files. What I want to do is automatically detect delimiter (not based on the file type but by reading the data).

Comment: @Henry If a file has data withing quotes ("") then most frequent would be the quotes and not the delimiter.

Comment: You could use Henry's approach and make an exception if the supposed delimiter character is within the quotes (e.g. use RegEx).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mathematically correct but totally useless answer: It's not possible.

Pragmatical answer: It's possible **but** it depends on how much you know about the file's structure. It boils down to a bunch of assumptions and depending on which we'll make, the answer will vary. And if you can't make any assumptions, well... see the mathematically correct answer.

For instance, can we assume that the delimiter is one or any of the elements in the set below?

```
List<char> delimiters = new List<char>{' ', ';', '|'};
```

Or can we assume that the delimiter is such that it produces elements of equal length?

Should we try to find a delimiter that's a single character or can a word be one?

Etc.

Based on the question, I'll assume that it's the first option and that we have a limited set of possible characters, precisely one of which is be a delimiter for a given file.

How about you count the number of occurrences of each such character and assume that the one that's occurring most frequently is the one? Is that sufficiently rigid or do you need to be more sure than that?

```
List<char> delimiters = new List<char>{' ', ';', '-'};
Dictionary<char, int> counts = delimiters.ToDictionary(key => key, value => 0);
foreach(char c in delimiters)
  counts[c] = textArray.Count(t => t == c);
```

I'm not in front of a computer so I can't verify but the last step would be returning the **key** from the dictionary the **value** of which is the maximal.

You'll need to take into consideration a special case such that there's no delimiters detected, there are equally many delimiters of two types etc.

Comment: The common delimiters that I would find would be a set of List<char> delimiters = new List<char>{' ', ';', '-', '|', ','};

Comment: @AMeh I think the idea is that most delimited formats would not have a restriction on other delimiters appearing inside of field content, so for example you could have `;` delimited text with `,` or `|` in a field and all would be detected. You could try to come up with some heuristic based on frequency perhaps, but without additional information I'm not sure you can know for certain. Could you elaborate on why you need to detect it automatically? Could the source of the data not provide additional information to be stored with it?

Comment: @ryachza I am running a test on textfieldparser class to read different types of files and display the data in a datagrid. I want to automate the process as much as I can for performance so if I want to read multiple files of different types in future, I can do so easily without spending much effort on figuring out the delimiters for each of those files..

Comment: @AMeh I'm not sure I understand what you mean by "for performance" - what are you trying to optimize? Regarding reading different file types - where are you getting the data that you're reading? I would expect your parser to act on (format,data) pairs rather than trying to re-detect the format each time the data is read?

Comment: @ryachza My guess is that OP wants to present the data and needs some facitlity to make it easier for him to delimit the read files. So the optimization isn't in terms of algorithm but rather not needing to investigate the file manually (probably, that is). He meant, probably, **automation** not **optimization**.

Comment: @KonradViltersten That's correct. And your solution worked too. There might be some assumptions in it but I think it is the best bet right now.

Comment: @KonradViltersten: You could expand your algorithm to make an additional assumption as well:  Most delimited files I have ever worked with contain the same number of fields per record.  This assumption might increase the "sureness" of the result.

Comment: @SamAxe You're correct. It's the second of the assumptions I've discussed in my answer. However, for the sake of helpfulness, I assumed that the OP wanted something "good enough", which simply was checking which of the character in a set of three that's frequently used. Apparently, I got it right for this case. However, as I said first - you're correct that there's still a lot of room to improve the approach. Just remember YAGNI, mate.

Answer (score 2):

Very simple guessing approach using LINQ:

```
static class CsvSeperatorDetector
{
    private static readonly char[] SeparatorChars = {';', '|', '\t', ','};

    public static char DetectSeparator(string csvFilePath)
    {
        string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(csvFilePath);
        return DetectSeparator(lines);
    }

    public static char DetectSeparator(string[] lines)
    {
        var q = SeparatorChars.Select(sep => new
                {Separator = sep, Found = lines.GroupBy(line => line.Count(ch => ch == sep))})
            .OrderByDescending(res => res.Found.Count(grp => grp.Key > 0))
            .ThenBy(res => res.Found.Count())
            .First();

        return q.Separator;
    }
}
```

What this does is it reads the file line by line (note that CSV files may include line breaks), then checks for each potential separator how often it occurs in each line.
Then we check which separator occurs on the most lines, and of those which occur on the same number of lines, we take the one with the most even distribution (e.g. 5 occurences on every line are ranked higher than one that occurs once in one line and 10 times in another line).
Of course you might have to tweak this for your own purposes, add error handling, fallback logic and so forth. I'm sure it's not perfect, but it's good enough for me.

Comment: I used this solution and it works well except little issue I found. When Count == 0 for all delimiters from SeparatorChars collection it returns first separator from the list. This needs to be taken under consideration when using that solution.

Answer (score 0):

You could probably take n bytes from the file, count possible delimiter characters(or all characters found) using a hash map/dictionary, and then the character repeated most is probably the delimiter you're looking for. It would make sense to me that the characters used as delimiters would be the ones used the most. When done you reset the stream, but since you're using a text reader you would have to probably initialize another text reader or something. This would get slightly more hairy if the CSV used more than one delimiter. You would probably have to ignore some characters like alpha and numeric.

Answer (score 0):

In python we can do this easily by using csv sniffer. It will cater for text files and also if you just need to read some bytes from the file.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30039901)